# AmCharts 4 - multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, amcharts

please, I'm trying to create with AmCharts 4 chart with multiple data sets. In previous version it is done this way: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/
but I can't find anything how to make it in 4th version.
I use the code from their website.
Everything is ok, next chart I want to add in section starting with comment **add ATR -> I need to show it under the original chart.**

Thank you very much for any help.
Have a nice day!

```
var chart = am4core.create("candlestick-chart", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

// chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd";
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "x";

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

/*
    add default series
 */

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.CandlestickSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "close";
series.dataFields.openValueY = "open";
series.dataFields.lowValueY = "low";
series.dataFields.highValueY = "high";
series.dataFields.atr = "atr";
series.dataFields.average_atr = "average_atr";
series.simplifiedProcessing = true;
series.tooltipText = "Open:${openValueY.value}\nLow:${lowValueY.value}\nHigh:${highValueY.value}\nClose:${valueY.value}\nATR:{atr.formatNumber('#.000')}\nAverage ATR:{average_atr.formatNumber('#.000')}";

series.riseFromPreviousState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
series.dropFromPreviousState.properties.fillOpacity = 0;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();


/*
    add scrollbar
 */
// a separate series for scrollbar
var scrollbarSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
scrollbarSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
scrollbarSeries.dataFields.valueY = "close";
// need to set on default state, as initially series is "show"
scrollbarSeries.defaultState.properties.visible = false;

// hide from legend too (in case there is one)
scrollbarSeries.hiddenInLegend = true;
scrollbarSeries.fillOpacity = 0.5;
scrollbarSeries.strokeOpacity = 0.5;

var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
scrollbarX.series.push(scrollbarSeries);
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;



/*
    add ATR
    -> I need to show it under the original chart
 */
var lineSeriesATR = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeriesATR.dataFields.dateX = "date";
lineSeriesATR.dataFields.valueY = "atr";
lineSeriesATR.defaultState.properties.visible = false;

// hide from legend too (in case there is one)
lineSeriesATR.hiddenInLegend = true;
lineSeriesATR.fillOpacity = 0.5;
lineSeriesATR.strokeOpacity = 0.5;


chart.data = {!! json_encode($candles) !!};
```

Comment: I would recommend going for chart.js. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmCharts 4 does not have the stock chart implemented yet. You can approximate panels and synced cursor and zoom by using the chart's [containers](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/svg-engine/containers/) to create additional charts and using the API to make the cursor and scrollbar affect all the charts.

You can create each chart and push them onto the chart container like so:

```
var container = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4core.Container); //create the container
container.width = am4core.percent(100); //set dimensions and layout
container.height = am4core.percent(100);
container.layout = "vertical";
// ... for each chart
 var chart = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);
// ..set up as usual
```

While setting up each chart, you'll need to set up events to sync up zoom events:

```
  // whenever any of the charts is zoomed, we should zoom all other charts
  dateAxis.events.on("selectionextremeschanged", function (event) {
    syncDateAxes(event.target);
  })
  // ...

function syncDateAxes(syncWithAxis) {
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
    if (dateAxis != syncWithAxis) {
      dateAxis.events.disableType("selectionextremeschanged");
      dateAxis.start = syncWithAxis.start;
      dateAxis.end = syncWithAxis.end;
      dateAxis.events.enableType("selectionextremeschanged");
    }
  }
}
```

You'll also want to set up each chart's cursor and sync each  of them up:

```
function initCursorListeners() {
  cursorShowDisposers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;
    cursor.interactionsEnabled = true;

    cursorShowDisposers.push(cursor.events.on("shown", function (event) {
      handleShowCursor(event.target);
    }));
  }
}

var shownCursorChangeDisposer;
var shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer;
var shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer;

function handleShowCursor(shownCursor) {
  // disable mouse for all other cursors
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;
    if (cursor != shownCursor) {
      cursor.interactionsEnabled = false;
    }
    // remove show listener
    cursorShowDisposers[i].dispose();
  }

  // add change disposer to the hovered chart cursor
  shownCursorChangeDisposer = shownCursor.lineX.events.on("positionchanged", function (event) {
    syncCursors(shownCursor);
  });


  shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer = shownCursor.events.on("zoomstarted", function (event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      if (cursor != event.target) {
        var point = { x: event.target.point.x, y: 0 };
        cursor.triggerDown(point);
      }
    }
  });

  shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer = shownCursor.events.on("zoomended", function (event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      if (cursor != event.target) {
        var point = { x: event.target.point.x, y: 0 };
        cursor.triggerUp(point);
      }
    }
  });


  shownCursor.events.once("hidden", function (event) {
    shownCursorChangeDisposer.dispose();
    shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer.dispose();
    shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer.dispose();

    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      cursor.hide(0);

      cursorShowDisposers[i].dispose();
    }

    initCursorListeners();
  });
}

function syncCursors(syncWithCursor) {
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;

    var point = { x: syncWithCursor.point.x, y: 0 };

    if (cursor != syncWithCursor) {
      cursor.triggerMove(point);
    }
  }
}
```

There are other UI tweaks you can make like disabling the zoom out button on other charts except the top-most one as well as showing the date axis labels on just the last chart.

Here's a [full demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/mKmJOy?editors=0010) on how to do all of this. This is also included in the examples folder in the AmCharts zip file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Have a nice day

Comment: What’s the difference between using containers vs. series in a single chart? is containers better performance wise ? Cause series performance is awful when I have multiple charts on the same page with many datapoints in each series.

Comment: There is no difference, performance-wise. Have you looked at the performance tips at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/performance/? If that doesn't help and you're using date-based data, then consider using v3's stock charts for the time being until v4's stock chart is ready.

Comment: @xorspark if you were to modify/refactor this with the latest version of Amcharts 4, what would you change?

Comment: @xorspark I am needing to synchronize multiple charts by (1. cursor movement (2. zoom effects (3. Single XYChartScrollbar on the date axis.

Please I couldn't get your demo to work 100% to meet these needs.

Comment: @ChukwumaNwaugha - A couple of things. 1) The demo works in the latest release of AmCharts 4, as you can see in the codepen. No refactoring is needed, so your first question is not even relevant. 2) Hijacking an answer to a two year old question for a different request is against SO rules.  Ask a new question and someone will respond.

Comment: It's a great example. I recommend directly looking at the Demo linked

Answer (score 0):

> If you're using Stock Chart, you might want to hold off.
>
> Stock chart is not yet available for V4. We're planning it for the
>   second part of 2018. No exact ETA, yet. Sorry.

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/#No_Stock_chart_yet